# Characters changing after export to .csv R

Tags: r

Having an issue understanding why these numbers are exporting in this manner yet in Rstudio they appear just fine. I'm sure its a file formatting issue but I don't understand how to check what It is and what it is exporting as to make it change.

**chr in df**

```
6½ | -105 | 6½ +105
```

**in .csv after export**

```
6┬╜ | -105 | 6┬╜┬á+105
```

**Code Below:**

```
    library(rvest)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tm)
    library(stringi)
    library(readr)


    tomorrow <- Sys.Date()
    tomorrow <- gsub("-", "", tomorrow, fixed=TRUE)

    print(tomorrow)

    url <- read_html(paste0('https://classic.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nhl-hockey/totals/?date=', as.character(tomorrow)))


    rot <- url %>%
      html_nodes('.eventLine-rotation .eventLine-book-value') %>%
      html_text()

    teams <- url %>%
      html_nodes('.team-name a') %>%
      html_text()

    total <- url %>%
      html_nodes('.adjust')%>%
      html_text()

    opening <- url %>%
      html_nodes('.price') %>%
      html_text()

    pinnacle <- url %>%
      html_nodes('.eventLine-book:nth-child(10) b') %>%
      html_text()

    dimes <- url %>%
      html_nodes('.eventLine-book:nth-child(11) b') %>%
      html_text()

    BookMaker <- url %>%
      html_nodes('.eventLine-book:nth-child(12) b') %>%
      html_text()

    BETONLINE <- url %>%
      html_nodes('.eventLine-book:nth-child(13) b') %>%
      html_text()

    BOVADA <- url %>%
      html_nodes('.eventLine-book:nth-child(14) b') %>%
      html_text()

    HERITAGE <- url %>%
      html_nodes('.eventLine-book:nth-child(15) b') %>%
      html_text()

    roster <- data.frame(ROT = rot, TEAM = teams, Total = total, OPENER = opening, PINNACLE = pinnacle,
                          FiveDimes = dimes, BOVADA = BOVADA, BETONLINE = BETONLINE,
                          HERITAGE = HERITAGE, BookMaker = BookMaker)

    write_delim(roster,'NHL_TOTALS_TODAY.csv', delim = ',')
```

Comment: This is strange, because according to the documentation for `write_delim`, all columns are supposed to be encoded as UTF-8, which should support the special characters in your data.

Comment: How are you opening the csv file? If I run your code and open the file, it looks fine in Notepad but gets scrambled in Excel. So maybe the issue is more with the program you're using to check the csv?

Comment: I am opening it in excel.

Comment: I also exported to file then opened in Notepad and that was fine. However I do need this file to open with excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed your `write_delim` to `write_excel_csv`, and it opened in my excel as it is supposed to do so.

I had the same error, just make that switch.

A little late, I know. Good luck and good betting.